# JBoss 5.1.0 to Wildfly

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-8

We are developing a new project (spring, mvc, jdbc, rest) which we are considering to deploy it in JBoss Wildfly 8.1.0. Before we were using the JBoss 5.1.0 where we had datasource and other configurations easily created and configured along with the war file. As I am trying to learn the Wildfly I feel it has datasources and other things to be configured separately through cli or ui console.

- Instead every developer in this project configuring the datasource manually on their system-server for development, is there a way to run a script to generate datasource or other way to have a single server configured with everything the project requires so that the developers can deploy their modules (war) and test it?
- I see the Wildfly has two modes, domain mode and standalone mode. Is this domain and "5.1.0 domain" are different? Which is the right mode to run the server in production? I am testing my application for now in standalone mode. From the jboss doc, I see this domain is for managing the app if it is deployed in a cluster. (This project under development is non-clustered single node web-application.)
- How to deploy more than one web-applications in a single Wildfly server? Do I need to create domains for every application?
  How to configure app specific property files in Wildfly? (We had a prop directory created under the jbossserver/default/deploy/prop/application.properties)

Comment: So you've basically not read the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Documentation . Which also has a migration guide: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+WildFly

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use CLI to create datasource from command. With CLI commands you can create script also. You can find it on Google. It will be server specific and no need to create in your project.
2. If you don't want to run jboss in cluster mode then you can use
   standalone.
3. You can deploy any number of web application. You need not to create
   domain. Just create WAR files and deploy. You can copy WAR files in {JBOSS_HOME}\standalone\deployments folder.